# How do I set the default value for a Dojo FilteringSelect using a JsonRest Store

Tags: javascript, json, dojo

I've successfully setup my FilteringSelect to query my server for items dynamically using the JsonRest store. My problem is when I try to initially set the dropdown with specific value.

```
<div id="ddThings"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">

    dojo.ready(function () {

            var storeThings = new dojo.store.JsonRest({ target: "/Things/" });
            var ddThings = new dijit.form.FilteringSelect({
                name: "thingId",
                searchAttr: "name",
                autoComplete: true,
                value: "5",
                missingMessage: "This is required",
                placeHolder: "Select a Thing",
                store: dojo.data.ObjectStore({ objectStore: storeThings })
        }, "ddThings");

        ddThings.startup();

        //ddThings.set("value", "5");

    });
```

When I set value to "5" or using ddThings.set I can see the filteringselect querying my server and passing in an "id" value. I return a collection of things with the single item in it. I expected it to populated the filteringselect with the item I returned. But, instead nothing happens.

The returned JSON looks like this

```
[
   {
      "id":"5",
      "name":"Example"
   }
]
```

One interesting note is that if I set "displayedValue" to "Example" (whatever the name is) then I can see it hit the server, find a match and return it and it actually populates the dropdown with the matching item. I want this behavior but by using the value/id of the item, not the display/name of it.

Comment: I'm not very familiar with `JsonRest`, and its expectations aren't necessarily well-documented, but I would wager a guess that it's not expecting a query for a specific ID to return an array.  Have you tried just returning a single object?

Comment: Ken, you're a genius! That was it! I never thought to return a single entity since usually I use the JsonRest store with a Grid which always needs a collection. I'll give you a chance to write it up as an answer  to get credit.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the JsonRest Store makes a request for a specific item by its id the response must be a single item instead of a collection.

```
{
   "id":"5",
   "name":"Example"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

dijit.form.FilteringSelect store is expecting a JSON object that looks like this.

```
{ "identifier":"id"
, "label":"name"
, "items":
    [
        {"id":"9","name":"Alberta"}
      , {"id":"4","name":"New Brunswick"}
      , {"id":"11","name":"Northwest Territories"}
    ]
}
```

The store must implement the dojo.data.api.Identity

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/dojo/data/api/Identity.html#dojo-data-api-identity

From the Dojo documentation:

> note: When using a DataStore with FilteringSelect, the store must
>   implement the Identity API.

http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dijit/form/FilteringSelect

Comment: The thing is all other functionality is working fine. Only the setting of a default value is broken. Yes, I've seen that data structure before. The problem is that's not how the JsonRest store works. If I just return the data in that format then it doesn't work. The problem then must be with the dojo.data.ObjectStore which is just an adapter between the old Data store technique and new Object stores. So, now I need to find out how to configure the Object store to behave properly.

Comment: How do know that all other functionality is working fine? When you click on the FilteringSelect, do you see all the values from the store? If you can't set the value, it's probably because the value wasn't found in the store and FilteringSelect won't let you set a value that's not in the store. I normally use `dojox.data.QueryReadStore` with `dijit.form.FilteringSelect` though because I don't really need to PUT/POST/DELETE anything in a FilteringSelect.

Comment: Yes, typing, searching and clicking the dropdown causes a query to execute and hits my server and populates it. For what it's worth I did get everything working (including the default) when I use a QueryReadStore. I was just hoping to start moving away from dojo.data since I was under the impression they were slowly being deprecated. I will mark this as the answer for now. It seems the only way to get full functionality is to use a QueryReadStore. Thanks

Comment: I'm not sure why this answer was accepted, because it's technically incorrect.  The format expected is dictated by the store, not the widget.  The format posted in the answer applies only to `dojo.data.ItemFileReadStore`, `dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore`, and (with minor differences) `dojox.data.QueryReadStore`.

Comment: Yes, but the solution is to basically not use the JsonRest store as it has issues with the FilteringSelect apparently. I marked it as the answer because for now it seems you must use the QueryReadStore to get full functionality.

Comment: @KenFranqueiro Correct, it's the store that must implement the Identity API not the widget and I clarified that in my answer before it was accepted but I'll add a little more to avoid confusion.

Comment: Thanks for everyone's help. Ken actually figured it out. It had to do with how the results were being returned. Interesting enough when you use the JsonRest store and it requests it by Id then you must return a single item. The QueryReadStore seems to be a more forgiving in that it was ok with getting a collection with a single item.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a dojo.store.DataStore as an adapter while all the widgets haven't been updated to the new dojo store api.

See http://livedocs.dojotoolkit.org/dojo/store/DataStore